# How to complete the puzzle in the "Highest Point" room?

Tags: antichamber

I am trying to complete the puzzle on the highest point room to get the red gun. I think I'm controlling the yellow gun wrong. Is there a way to drag through glass that I'm not getting?

Answer (score 1):

You need lots of cubes since you cannot drag through glasses.

The yellow gun has a cool ability:

1. aim at a yellow block,
2. press and hold middle-click,
3. aim at a place where there is no block,
4. finally release all the keys pressed,
5. the connected yellow blocks will behave like a 3D snake
6. the snake will try to move in a straight line to the position you had indicated.

Make sure the snake enters through a big hole in the glass and then drag it using the tail of the snake, which should still be hanging out of the glass window through the entry hole.

An interesting property of the middle-click action is that while you hold it, you can move your cursor from one yellow block to another, and what matters is only the yellow block your cursor is on when you release the key pressed.

In summary:

1. make sure you have a sufficiently long snake
2. aim at a block outside the pane window
3. drag your cursor to a block inside the pane window
4. move this block to a new position

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to change which block you are "pulling on"

1. aim at a yellow block on the tail sticking out
2. press and hold middle-click
3. aim at another yellow block
4. focus will now change to pull on that block (see the rings)
5. aim where you want them to go and release.

Comment: It is important to note that while the first block can not be behind glass, the second can.

Answer (score 0):

Im at the same point and i think i have just figured it out. You want to get close to the glass so you aim slightly behind it. You need to aim at an available yellow block, then drag your mouse to the one closest the wire you are trying to activate.

You then drag the yellow blocks into a circle to create new ones. Tricky.